# Angular 4 : disable button as long as form not validated

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have a form with required fields and 2 buttons : first button submits the form and another button is to download the file.

On the one hand, as long as form is not valid, the submit button is disabled (and it enables when the form is valid) :

**component.html** :

`<button type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroupTest.valid" >Valider</button>`

=> It works

On the other hand, as long as form is not valid, the "download" button is disabled and it enables when : form valid AND button submit is clicked :

**component.html** :

`<button [disabled]="!formGroupTest.valid || !buttonSubmitEnabled">Download</button>`

For that, in **component.ts**, i initialize a boolean at false, and it becomes true when button submit clicked (method sendForm())  :

```
private buttonSubmitEnabled: boolean = false; 

sendForm() {
    this.buttonSubmitEnabled=true;
}
```

When I fill the form for the first time, it works perfectly => I click on the submit button and the download button becomes enable. However, after the first time, if I decide to change required fields and it returns the form as invalid, the 2 buttons are disabled (logically), but when I fill the fields correctly then the "download" button becomes enable. I understood the problem, because the 2 conditions to enable the button download are respected : Form valid AND button submit clicked once.

So, what if I want it to work every time, I think it's necessary to put the Boolean "buttonSubmitEnabled" at false each time the form is invalid, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you can use `formGroupTest.submitted` flag of form.

Comment: Can you explain/expand that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FormGroup` has a `valueChanges` property that you can `subscribe` to. Every form change will trigger this observable. You can use this to reset the submission boolean.

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.buttonSubmitEnabled = false);
```

Comment: Thank you, but where in the component can i change this value ? At what thime or in which function ?

Comment: @Josept after this.myForm is initialize

Answer (score 2):

In keyup event of those input fields call a function `disableDownload()`

```
<input (keyup)="disableDownload()">
```

And inside disableDownload(), just make download buttonSubmitEnabled **false**

```
disableDownload() {
   this.buttonSubmitEnabled = false;    
}
```

Only make the **buttonSubmitEnabled** true once the form is submitted